# What kind of file is this?

Tags: mysql, file-format

I don't known the full story as I just got involved recently but I have a file that is "a MySQL data base" (longish story, the source is not technical).

The file name is: `something.db`

the Linux `file` command just gives `data`

looking inside I find `Copyright (c)2000 9.0.0.1108` [`Sybase`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybase) (might be an author or file format vendor)

I'm supposed to be striping the data out of the file but first I need to known what type it is.

Comment: I'm wanting to find someone who /knows/ rather than just /suspects/

Answer (score 1):

If it's Sybase, my guess would be it's a [SQLAnywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Anywhere) database.

Comment: I'm sucking that stuff down now.

Comment: I think so, I'm not going to get my hopes up till I actually get data out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, [vendor linkage](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/sqlanywhere) .